# not able to align text in listview

Tags: android, listview

Just not able to align the text in my listview to right/left. Not sure how to do that. Android:gravity does not seem to work.

here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background= "#FFCC00"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" 
        android:background= "#FFCC00"
        android:textColor="#330033"
        android:gravity="left">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookMark"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bookmarks"
        android:textColor="#330033"
        android:background= "#CCCC99"
        android:onClick="loadBookmarks"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the code to populate the listview

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row_listview, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Stories)));
```

Comment: i cant understand what u want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to change the text in the textview inside R.layout.row_listview.
Please share the code inside row_listview.xml, so we can help you.

Comment: somehow I cannot see row_listview.xml in eclipse package explorer. I can however see that xml under my folder structure in res/layout in my windows explorer. I can see that value of gravity in textview there is "center". I guess that is the culprit. I am however perplexed as to why does row_listview does not showup in eclipse package explorer.

Comment: i could solve it by correctinng the gravity in row_listview.xml. I was looking for that xml in the wrong place. Thanks conrad for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are looking for.

`android:textAlignment="center"`

Also using `android:gravity` only works if the total text is smaller than the view. So if you have "wrap content" then i dont think it will work. Atleast that is what it says on the site [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity)

Below i have added a sample layout and related code for a row that aligns two textviews to the left and right sides of the row

```
 private ListView lv = null;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflate, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result = inflate.inflate(R.layout.lists_layout, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, things, R.layout.rowLayout, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

listLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

</ListView>
```

rowLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingRight="5dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textleft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to align my text to left. But using android:textAlignment="left" throws xml error saying "string type not allowed". Also I don't have "wrap_content". I have width and height as fill_parent.

Comment: Either way. If you are using eclipse you might be missing a key feature in it. Highlight the text inside of the quotes and press ctrl space. This will give you possible values for that field. Also you can look these values up in the TextView link that i posted in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip, being new to eclipse, I was not aware of ctrl space thing. I however tried all the values, but alignment still is center.